# trösten + Personalpronomen im Akkusativ: "Die andere Frau tröstet sie"

Tags: grammar

> Die eine Frau weint und die andere Frau *tröstet sie*.

Can *trösten* be used together in a sentence with a personal pronoun in accusative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can. `trösten` demands an object in accusative. This object can be any nominal group for example a single personal pronoun.

Comment: Trösten can be used intransitively as in 'er spottet, sie tröstet' *(he's taunting, she's comforting)*, commonly used when describing a habitual action.

Comment: @collapsar... I would find that a bit odd and much prefer "spendet Trost". My Sprachgefühl really wants an object there